# Send current vim line to seperate tmux pane and move cursor down

Tags: key-bindings, tmux

I am trying to send the vim line that is under the cursor to another tmux pane and then move the cursor on vim down 1 line.

For context, I have vim open on 1 pane, and python open on another. I want to bind this capability to a key so that I may execute my python code line by line through vim.

Comment: That sounds like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754). Why don't you simply use a built-in mechanism like `:w` with `:.w !python` for example? Which you can map easily to `nnoremap <keytomap> :.w !python<CR>` you could even add `j` at the end of the mapping to go the next line.

Comment: Thank you, however I do not want to run the entire python file. I want to run 1 line at a time. There is similar functionality in, for example, Spyder IDE, where only the current line under the cursor is sent to the python console.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/19209/10604

Comment: Well `:.w !python` doesn't execute the whole file it takes `.` as an address to send the current line to python.

Answer (score 1):

The following function will send a paragraph of text or visually selected text to the tmux pane that corresponding to the count.

```
function! Send_to_tmux(visual, count) range abort
    if (a:visual)
        execute "normal! gv\"zy"
    else
        execute "normal! \"zyip"
    endif
    let text = @z
    let text = substitute(text, ';', '\\;', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '"', '\\"', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '\n', '" Enter "', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '!', '\\!', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '%', '\\%', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '#', '\\#', 'g')
    silent execute "!tmux send-keys -t " . a:count . " -- \"" . text . "\""
    silent execute "!tmux send-keys -t " . a:count . "Enter"
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>p :<C-u>call Send_to_tmux(0, v:count1)<CR>
xnoremap <Leader>p :<C-u>call Send_to_tmux(1, v:count1)<CR>
```

For, example, you want to send a line to adjacent tmux pane and move down one line in vim, you can adjust the function somewhat like the following:

```
function! Send_to_tmux(visual, count) range abort
    execute "normal! vg_o^\"zy"
    let text = @z
    let text = substitute(text, ';', '\\;', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '"', '\\"', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '\n', '" Enter "', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '!', '\\!', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '%', '\\%', 'g')
    let text = substitute(text, '#', '\\#', 'g')
    silent execute "!tmux send-keys -t " . a:count . " -- \"" . text . "\""
    silent execute "!tmux send-keys -t " . a:count . "Enter"
    normal! j
endfunction
nnoremap <Leader>p :<C-u>call Send_to_tmux(0, v:count1)<CR>
xnoremap <Leader>p :<C-u>call Send_to_tmux(1, v:count1)<CR>
```

The above function will send the current line to the tmux pane corresponding to the count, i.e. if you press `2<Leader>p` then the text will go the tmux pane number 2 and so on. Also, the cursor will go one line down.